# Cross-Compiling Linux Kernel for Raspberry Pi - ${CCPREFIX}gcc -v does not work

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://frec.pl/blog/compiling-custom-raspberry-pi-kernel-with-kedei-35/). I'm running both Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64) on "real" hardware and 14.04.1 via VirtualBox on my Mac. The problem is that I don't even get past Step 1:

```
hoffmann@angl99:~$ export CCPREFIX=/home/hoffmann/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
hoffmann@angl99:~$ ${CCPREFIX}gcc -v
```

I'm then getting the following error:

```
-bash: /home/hoffmann/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory
```

However, the file that I'm told is missing is certainly there:

```
hoffmann@angl99:~$ less /home/hoffmann/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
"/home/hoffmann/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

This is probably the result of a basic error/misconception. Could anybody suggest a solution?
Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=26628 If you want just the kernel use './build -packages kernel bcm2709'.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I've worked it out (with the help of the person who posted the guide I'm trying to follow). It was indeed a basic issue...
The cross compiler binaries I was going to use are 32-bit and I was running a 64-bit system. I've now installed a 32-bit Ubuntu on VirtualBox and everything is running smoothly.